# Add metric to determine the quality of an edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, metrics

I make *many edits*.  I'm not necessarily looking for an acknowledgement (although it would be nice), but I think it would be great if at least, I could see metrics relating to edits.

What I'd *really like* however, is to see some way of determining whether or not the edit was a "quality" edit.

What does that mean?  I would say that the following contributes to a quality edit:

- Corrects punctuation, spelling, grammar
- Re-tags which identify the question more accurately
- Applies formatting to make more readable
- Adds links to specific resources which are relevant (I'd go so far as to remove bare links and apply them to the appropriate areas of text)

Obviously, it's open to interpretation, but I think that starting in some direction to identify this is a good idea (it would also help when it comes to moderator elections).

Comment: Since it's so open to interpretation, please feel free to give us your take: http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jon Seigel: That's impossible to do with [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com); it's not about the numbers, it's about the content.  I can create a query which tells me *what* has changed but it's impossible using that tool to make any of the interpretations above to determine quality of the edit.  It would require analysis of the content returned from the query, not just the content itself (not knocking the tool, it's cool, and I like it, but it's not able to give you suggestions, just data that should be processed, not *how* to process it).